# Menu with Password and Simple Order

Tags: java, menu

Create a program that require a password before making an order. After successfully entering the password, the customer should see a welcome message. Then a menu after that. The customer should be able to see options from the menu and the sub-menus. The order (with prices) should be completed before the customer can exit the program.

In my code below, it stays at asking for the password, I don't know what to do next. Also, the order should be counted and appears at the last part before the customer exits. Kindly walk me through this!

Welcome to Favor Stuff (Party Giveaways)

Please select from the available menu.

A. Marlboro Lights

```
1. Soft Pack 70.00

2. Flip Top 80.00
```

B. Marlboro Red

```
1. Soft Pack 70.00

2. Flip Top  80.00
```

C. Dunhill

```
1. Soft Pack 60.00

2. Flip Top 70.00
```

D. Phillip

```
1. Soft Pack 70.00

2. Flip Top 80.00





import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class MenuORDER {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int attempts = 0;
        String Order;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = null;
        String CORRECT_PWORD = "1234";

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
            password = keyboard.next();
            if (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD)) {
                System.out.println("Password is incorrect!");
                attempts++;
            }
        } while (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD) && attempts <3);


        if (password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD)) {

            System.out.println("Welcome to Favor Stuff (Party Giveaways)!");
            do {
            System.out.println("Please select from the available options below! ");
            System.out.println("A. Marlboro Lights");
            System.out.println("B. Marlboro Red");
            System.out.println("C. Dunhill");
            System.out.println("D. Phillip");   

            System.out.print("Sellect your brand: ");   
            System.out.println("");
            String Price = keyboard.nextLine();
            String Price1 = "";
            String Price2 = "";

                switch (Price) {
                case "A": Price1 = "Soft Pack 70.00";
                        break;
                case "B": Price2 = "Flip Top 80.00";
                        break;
                case "C": Price1 = "Soft Pack 70.00";
                        break;
                case "D": Price2 = "Flip Top 80.00";
                        break;
                case "E": Price1 = "Soft Pack 70.00";
                        break;
                case "F": Price2 = "Flip Top 80.00";
                        break;
                case "G": Price1 = "Soft Pack 70.00";
                        break;
                case "H": Price2 = "Flip Top 80.00";
                        break;
                case "I": Price1 = "Soft Pack 70.00";
                        break;
                case "J": Price2 = "Flip Top 80.00";
                        break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                        break;
                }
                System.out.println("Thank you! Your order is " + brand + Price);

            }while (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD));
    }while (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD) && attempts <3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by mapping out what it is you need to do.  You need to be able to validate a user's password, okay, kind of got that.  Once you know if the user is validated or not, you need to display a menu and process the options, this can all be done in a single loop

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you make an example for the loop Sir/Ma'am! I have the options above. @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by breaking down your requirements, first you need to validate the user...

```
int attempts = 0;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String password = null;
String CORRECT_PWORD = "1234";
String Options = null;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter Pin Code: ");
    password = keyboard.next();
    if (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD)) {
        System.out.println("Password is incorrect!");
        attempts++;
    }
} while (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD) && attempts < 3);
```

Either they enter the correct password or they fail.  Based on the result, you need to make a decision about what to do next...

```
if (password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD)) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Favor Stuff (Party Giveaways)!");
    // Only valid user options should appear here...
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry but you can no longer continue!:");
}

// Program is allowed to terminate naturally
```

So, in you "valid user" section, you want to show your main menu...

```
if (password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD)) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Favor Stuff (Party Giveaways)!");
    String option = null;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please select from the available options below! ");
        System.out.println("A. Truffled Boxes");
        System.out.println("B. Candy Jars");
        System.out.println("C. Jellies");
        System.out.println("D. Cupcakes");
        System.out.println("E. Bride and Groom");
        System.out.println("X. Exit");
        option = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (option.equals("A")) {
            String subOption = null;
            do {
                System.out.println("1. Truffled Boxes with two (2) truffles and personalized thank you tags");
                System.out.println("2. Truffled Boxes with four (4) truffles and personalized thank you tags");
                System.out.println("3. Truffled Boxes with six (6) truffles and personalized thank you tags");
                System.out.println("0. Return");
                subOption = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (subOption.equals("1")) {

                } else if (subOption.equals("2")) {
                } else if (subOption.equals("3")) {
                } else if (subOption.equals("0")) {
                // Do nothing, but don't want to display
                    // invalid entry message
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
                }
            } while (!subOption.equalsIgnoreCase("0"));
        } else if (option.equals("B")) {
            // Candy jars...
        } else if (option.equals("C")) {
            // Jellies...
        } else if (option.equals("D")) {
            // Candy Cupcakes...
        } else if (option.equals("E")) {
            // Bride groom...
        } else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
        // Do nothing, but don't want to display
            // invalid entry message
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
        }
    } while (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("x"));
}
```

This main loop is responsible for all the options in the main menu.  Each sub section will have it's own input loop as well.  If you've done any work on methods, I'd break all this down into it's own method(s) to make life easier.

To keep track of the orders, there are a number of possible solutions, you could, for example, create a `Product` class, which has information about each product (name, price), then create a `Order` class which has information about the `Product` been ordered and the quantity.  This is probably the preferred way.  But simpler, hackier way would be to define a series of keys...

```
public static final String TRUFFLE_BOXES_2 = "Truffle Boxes with (2) truffles and personalized thank you tags";
public static final String TRUFFLE_BOXES_4 = "Truffle Boxes with (4) truffles and personalized thank you tags";
public static final String TRUFFLE_BOXES_6 = "Truffle Boxes with (6) truffles and personalized thank you tags";

public static final String CANDY_MARSHMELLOW = "Marshmallow";
public static final String CANDY_CHOCOLATE = "Chocolate";
public static final String CANDY_COOKIES = "Cookies";

public static final String JELLIES_JELLY_BEANS = "Jelly Beans";

public static final String CUP_CAKES_REGULAR = "Regular cupcake box";
public static final String CUP_CAKES_REGULAR_BULK = "Regular cupcake box by bulk";

public static final String BRIDE_AND_GROOM_BOX = "Bride and groom box (per pair)";
```

These represent quick and easy keys to perform lookups against `Map`s

You would then define the prices for each of the products/keys

```
Map<String, Double> prices = new HashMap<>(10);
prices.put(TRUFFLE_BOXES_2, 45.00);
prices.put(TRUFFLE_BOXES_4, 50.00);
prices.put(TRUFFLE_BOXES_6, 60.00);

prices.put(CANDY_MARSHMELLOW, 35.00);
prices.put(CANDY_CHOCOLATE, 50.00);
prices.put(CANDY_COOKIES, 45.00);

prices.put(JELLIES_JELLY_BEANS, 45.00);

prices.put(CUP_CAKES_REGULAR, 60.00);
prices.put(CUP_CAKES_REGULAR_BULK, 40.00);

prices.put(BRIDE_AND_GROOM_BOX, 70.00);
```

Then you could keep track the order using something like...

```
Map<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>(25);
order.put(CANDY_CHOCOLATE, 10);
order.put(CUP_CAKES_REGULAR, 5);
order.put(CANDY_COOKIES, 12);
```

And when required, present a tally

```
double total = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : order.entrySet()) {

    int quanity = entry.getValue();
    double price = prices.get(entry.getKey());

    total += quanity * price;

    System.out.println(String.format(
                    "%-20s x %4d @ %7s = %10s",
                    entry.getKey(),
                    quanity,
                    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price),
                    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(quanity * price)));

}

System.out.printf("%-20s   %4s   %7s   ==========%n", "", "", "");
System.out.printf("%-20s   %4s   %7s   %10s%n", "", "", "", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total));
```

which in this prints

```
Chocolate            x   10 @  $50.00 =    $500.00
Cookies              x   12 @  $45.00 =    $540.00
Regular cupcake box  x    5 @  $60.00 =    $300.00
                                        ==========
                                         $1,340.00
```

> I want to change the options into Cigar brands, and use switch so it would be better... but add the prices at the end just like what you did with the previous one.. I'm confused

I'm about to confuse the crap out of you (again)...

Basically, this is your entire (update) program, items, prices, menus, tally.

It makes use of the `Map`'s of items, orders, prices and groups to generate your entire program.

The "data" is all variable, but the way that the menu and ordering system works doesn't need to change when you create/add/remove products

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestShop {

    public static final String MALBORO_LIGHTS = "Malboro Lights";
    public static final String MALBORO_LIGHTS_SOFT = "Marlboro Lights, Soft Pack";
    public static final String MALBORO_LIGHTS_FLIP = "Marlboro Lights, Flip Pack";

    public static final String MALBORO_RED = "Malboro Reds";
    public static final String MALBORO_RED_SOFT = "Marlboro Reds, Soft Pack";
    public static final String MALBORO_RED_FLIP = "Marlboro Reds, Flip Pack";

    public static final String DUNHILL = "Dunhill";
    public static final String DUNHILL_SOFT = "Dunhill, Soft Pack";
    public static final String DUNHILL_FLIP = "Dunhill, Flip Pack";

    public static final String PHILLIP = "Phillip";
    public static final String PHILLIP_SOFT = "Phillip, Soft Pack";
    public static final String PHILLIP_FLIP = "Phillip, Flip Pack";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestShop();
    }

    public TestShop() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        /**************************************************************************/
        /* This part is dynamic, change this when you want new items, prices or   */
        /* groups                                                                 */
        /**************************************************************************/

        // A list of items that have been ordered
        Map<String, Integer> orders = new HashMap<>(25);

        // A list of items keyed to prices
        Map<String, Double> prices = new HashMap<>(25);
        prices.put(MALBORO_LIGHTS_SOFT, 70d);
        prices.put(MALBORO_LIGHTS_FLIP, 80d);
        prices.put(MALBORO_RED_SOFT, 70d);
        prices.put(MALBORO_RED_FLIP, 80d);
        prices.put(DUNHILL_SOFT, 60d);
        prices.put(DUNHILL_FLIP, 70d);
        prices.put(PHILLIP_SOFT, 70d);
        prices.put(PHILLIP_FLIP, 80d);

        // Mapping items to groups...
        Map<String, List<String>> groups = new HashMap<>(25);
        groups.put(MALBORO_LIGHTS, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{MALBORO_LIGHTS_SOFT, MALBORO_LIGHTS_FLIP})));
        groups.put(MALBORO_RED, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{MALBORO_RED_SOFT, MALBORO_RED_FLIP})));
        groups.put(DUNHILL, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{DUNHILL_SOFT, DUNHILL_FLIP})));
        groups.put(PHILLIP, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{PHILLIP_SOFT, PHILLIP_FLIP})));

        /**************************************************************************/

        /**************************************************************************/
        /* The rest of this is pretty static and is driven by the data from above */
        /* This means, you don't need change anything below here, when the stuff  */
        /* changes                                                                */
        /**************************************************************************/

        boolean done = false;
        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome to my shop");
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(groups.keySet());
            for (int index = 0; index < keys.size(); index++) {
                System.out.println("[" + (index + 1) + "] " + keys.get(index));
            }
            System.out.println("[0] Exit");
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            try {
                int selectedIndex = Integer.parseInt(input);
                if (selectedIndex == 0) {
                    done = true;
                } else if (selectedIndex > 0 && selectedIndex <= keys.size()) {
                    String key = keys.get(selectedIndex - 1);

                    List<String> items = groups.get(key);
                    boolean subDone = false;
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Items for " + key + "....");
                        for (int index = 0; index < items.size(); index++) {
                            System.out.println("  [" + (index + 1) + "] " + items.get(index));
                        }
                        System.out.println("  [0] Return");
                        input = keyboard.nextLine();
                        try {
                            int index = Integer.parseInt(input);
                            if (index > 0 && index <= items.size()) {
                                index--; // The items in the list are 0 indexed
                                String item = items.get(index);
                                Integer quanity = orders.get(item);
                                if (quanity == null) {
                                    quanity = 1;
                                } else {
                                    quanity++;
                                }
                                orders.put(item, quanity);
                            } else if (index == 0) {
                                subDone = true;
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Invalid selection, please try again");
                            }
                        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                            System.out.println("!! " + input + " is not a valid selection");
                        }
                    } while (!subDone);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid selection, please try again");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                System.out.println("!! " + input + " is not a valid selection");
            }

        } while (!done);

        double total = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : orders.entrySet()) {

            int quanity = entry.getValue();
            double price = prices.get(entry.getKey());

            total += quanity * price;

            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "%-20s x %4d @ %7s = %10s",
                    entry.getKey(),
                    quanity,
                    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price),
                    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(quanity * price)));

        }

        System.out.printf("%-20s   %4s   %7s   ==========%n", "", "", "");
        System.out.printf("%-20s   %4s   %7s   %10s%n", "", "", "", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm only basing the suggestions on the code you had, if you need to include the prices then you will need to update the `System.out.println` statements to include them

Comment: But I don't know how to put the order with prices and how to make it appear with the final order

Comment: `System.out.println("1. Truffled Boxes with two (2) truffles and personalized thank you tags $45.00");`?

Comment: Okay, so you could have a `static` value for each element and the keep a count of how many you've ordered.  The problem here is, I don't if you're allowed to use `Map`s or not

Comment: still there? I'm waiting Sir! I have to finish this please!

Comment: Oh my God, I've seen this late hu hu hu.. I have changed the options to make it simpler for me, now I am more confused. My mistakes... I thought you are not there anymore, huhuhu @MadProgrammer so sorry for that..

Comment: I see.. can I disturb you for some more minutes if you are available, I want to change the options into Cigar brands, and use switch so it would be better... but add the prices at the end just like what you did with the previous one.. I'm confused.. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Changing the products generally isn't that hard, the way I've setup the static/product/keys gives you a good lace to start. Using case/switch isn't that hard, although you need to keep in mind that it's cSe sensitive.

Comment: I've edited my post so you can see. There's no more for suboptions. Look at how messy my codes are haha.. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @FinnDonovan That last update should have you ready to gouge your eyes out.  Basically, it's a complete runnable solution, based on your updated data.  I suggest you copy as a whole and run it, to see "what" it does, before you try and see "how" it does it

Comment: Oh, there is an error - error: invalid method declaration; return type required ---- C:\Users\Miles\Documents\MenuORDER.java:31: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public TestShop() {
           ^

Comment: @MapProgrammer Hi, it now compiles but you removed the password, also the selection is stuck at the submenu. I cannot proceed to selection between flip pack and soft pack.Anyways, I hope my teacher doesn't try to run it so he won't know. I have no more time left because I have 4 more  subjects to study for finals today. Thank you for your effort and time. I appreciate it much Sir! I will study it and try to debug later. Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to exit out of the sub menus by using "0". You should be able to put the password section from the start of the answer before this section ;)

Answer (score 0):

The result is okay but after  entering the password, this is what comes out

```
Enter Pin Code: 1234
Welcome to Favor Stuff (Party Giveaways)!
[1] Malboro Reds
[2] Malboro Lights
[3] Dunhill
[4] Phillip
[0] Exit
!!  is not a valid selection
[1] Malboro Reds
[2] Malboro Lights
[3] Dunhill
[4] Phillip
[0] Exit
```

Thi is the updated code

```
public class TestShop {

    public static final String MALBORO_LIGHTS = "Malboro Lights";
    public static final String MALBORO_LIGHTS_SOFT = "Marlboro Lights, Soft Pack";
    public static final String MALBORO_LIGHTS_FLIP = "Marlboro Lights, Flip Pack";

    public static final String MALBORO_RED = "Malboro Reds";
    public static final String MALBORO_RED_SOFT = "Marlboro Reds, Soft Pack";
    public static final String MALBORO_RED_FLIP = "Marlboro Reds, Flip Pack";

    public static final String DUNHILL = "Dunhill";
    public static final String DUNHILL_SOFT = "Dunhill, Soft Pack";
    public static final String DUNHILL_FLIP = "Dunhill, Flip Pack";

    public static final String PHILLIP = "Phillip";
    public static final String PHILLIP_SOFT = "Phillip, Soft Pack";
    public static final String PHILLIP_FLIP = "Phillip, Flip Pack";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestShop();
    }

    public TestShop() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**************************************************************************/
    /* This part is dynamic, change this when you want new items, prices or   */
    /* groups                                                                 */
    /**************************************************************************/

    // A list of items that have been ordered
    Map<String, Integer> orders = new HashMap<>(25);

    // A list of items keyed to prices
    Map<String, Double> prices = new HashMap<>(25);
    prices.put(MALBORO_LIGHTS_SOFT, 70d);
    prices.put(MALBORO_LIGHTS_FLIP, 80d);
    prices.put(MALBORO_RED_SOFT, 70d);
    prices.put(MALBORO_RED_FLIP, 80d);
    prices.put(DUNHILL_SOFT, 60d);
    prices.put(DUNHILL_FLIP, 70d);
    prices.put(PHILLIP_SOFT, 70d);
    prices.put(PHILLIP_FLIP, 80d);

    // Mapping items to groups...
    Map<String, List<String>> groups = new HashMap<>(25);
    groups.put(MALBORO_LIGHTS, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{MALBORO_LIGHTS_SOFT, MALBORO_LIGHTS_FLIP})));
    groups.put(MALBORO_RED, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{MALBORO_RED_SOFT, MALBORO_RED_FLIP})));
    groups.put(DUNHILL, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{DUNHILL_SOFT, DUNHILL_FLIP})));
    groups.put(PHILLIP, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{PHILLIP_SOFT, PHILLIP_FLIP})));

    /**************************************************************************/

    /**************************************************************************/
    /* The rest of this is pretty static and is driven by the data from above */
    /* This means, you don't need change anything below here, when the stuff  */
    /* changes                                                                */
    /**************************************************************************/


    int attempts = 0;

    String password = null;
    String CORRECT_PWORD = "1234";
    String Options = null;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Pin Code: ");
        password = keyboard.next();
        if (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD)) {
            System.out.println("Password is incorrect!");
            attempts++;
        }
    } while (!password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD) && attempts < 3);




    if (password.equals(CORRECT_PWORD)) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Favor Stuff (Party Giveaways)!");

    boolean done = false;
    do {

        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(groups.keySet());
        for (int index = 0; index < keys.size(); index++) {
            System.out.println("[" + (index + 1) + "] " + keys.get(index));
        }
        System.out.println("[0] Exit");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        try {
            int selectedIndex = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (selectedIndex == 0) {
                done = true;
            } else if (selectedIndex > 0 && selectedIndex <= keys.size()) {
                String key = keys.get(selectedIndex - 1);

                    List<String> items = groups.get(key);
                    boolean subDone = false;
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Items for " + key + "....");
                        for (int index = 0; index < items.size(); index++) {
                            System.out.println("  [" + (index + 1) + "] " + items.get(index));
                        }
                        System.out.println("  [0] Return");
                        input = keyboard.nextLine();
                        try {
                            int index = Integer.parseInt(input);
                            if (index > 0 && index <= items.size()) {
                                index--; // The items in the list are 0 indexed
                                String item = items.get(index);
                                Integer quanity = orders.get(item);
                                if (quanity == null) {
                                    quanity = 1;
                                } else {
                                    quanity++;
                                }
                                orders.put(item, quanity);
                            } else if (index == 0) {
                                subDone = true;
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Invalid selection, please try again");
                            }
                        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                            System.out.println("!! " + input + " is not a valid selection");
                        }
                    } while (!subDone);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid selection, please try again");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                System.out.println("!! " + input + " is not a valid selection");
            }

        } while (!done);

        double total = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : orders.entrySet()) {

            int quanity = entry.getValue();
            double price = prices.get(entry.getKey());

            total += quanity * price;

            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "%-20s x %4d @ %7s = %10s",
                    entry.getKey(),
                    quanity,
                    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price),
                    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(quanity * price)));

        }

        System.out.printf("%-20s   %4s   %7s   ==========%n", "", "", "");
       System.out.printf("%-20s   %4s   %7s   %10s%n", "", "", "", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total));

 } else {
    System.out.println("Sorry! You have entered the wrong password. Please call our Store 1234-567!");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer heres what I did... I cannot figure out how to clean that one.